# Add body class to category with all its subcategories | Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, categories, product

I want to add class to the body tag when viewing a category and all its subcategories, the code bellow work but it just add the class to the category in question but not all its subcategories:

```
add_filter( 'body_class','custom_body_class' );
function custom_body_class( $classes ) {

    if ( is_product_category( 802 ) ) {
        $classes[] = 'class1';
    } else if ( is_product_category( array( 'femme', 'homme', 'enfant' ) ) ) {
        $classes[] = 'class2';
    }

    return $classes;

}
```

I tried to replace `is_product_category` with `in_category` or is_product_tag but It does not work either.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question correctly. Do you want to add css class to the category page and all it's subcategory page? That say, I have a category named Fruit and the subcategory Apple, Lemon...and you want the subcategory page with Apple and Lemon all have css class name Fruit on it's body?

Comment: yes LoicTheAztec gived me the good solution, thanks anyway ucheng!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need instead to use the related WordPress conditional function [**`has_term()`**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_term) with the `'product_cat'` taxonomy argument to target product categories this way:

```
add_filter( 'body_class','custom_body_class' );
function custom_body_class( $classes ) {

    if ( has_term( 802, 'product_cat' ) ) { // assuming that 802 is the id of a product category.
        $classes[] = 'class1';
    } else if ( has_term( array( 'femme', 'homme', 'enfant' ), 'product_cat' ) ) {
        $classes[] = 'class2';
    }

    return $classes;

}
```

---

> **Update 2 (based on your comment):**

When archive category (or subcategory) pages are empty, is possible to use **`get_queried_object()`** function to get the current term object and adapt the conditions in your function to handle those cases.

Here is that code:

```
add_filter( 'body_class','custom_body_class' );
function custom_body_class( $classes ) {

    // Only on product category (or subcategory) archives pages     
    if(is_product_category()):

    // Set HERE your Main category ID (the parent ID of subcategories IDs)
    $main_cat = 802;

    // Set HERE your subcategories slugs
    $sub_cats_arr = array( 'femme', 'homme', 'enfant' );

    // Getting the current term (object) of category or subcategory archives page 
    $term = get_queried_object();

    // All the needed data from current term (object)
    $term_id = $term->term_id; // term ID
    $term_slug = $term->slug; // term slug
    $term_name = $term->name; // term name
    $term_taxonomy = $term->taxonomy; // Always 'product_cat' for woocommerce product categories
    $term_parent_id = $term->parent; // the parent term_id

    // FOR YOUR MAIN CATEGORY ID '802' (Handle empty archive page case too)
    if ( has_term( $main_cat, $term_taxonomy ) || $term_id == $main_cat )
        $classes[] = 'class1';

    // FOR YOUR MAIN 3 SUBCATEGORIES SLUGS (Handle empty archive page case too)
    if ( has_term( $sub_cats_arr, $term_taxonomy ) || in_array($term_slug, $sub_cats_arr) )
            $classes[] = 'class2';

    endif;

    return $classes;

}
```

This way you should avoid the case when viewing category or subcategory wich contain no product that doesn't add your body custom class…

Comment: When viewing category or subcategory wich contain no product, the class is not added, is it normal ? Is there a way to add the class anyway the category has a product or not ?

Comment: @colapsnux has_term() only works with post or custom posts as products… So Let me think it… For category without products you can combine has_term() with is_product_category() in the condition with an "OR"… But for subcategory without products, I don't know yet… I have to make some tests before giving a working solution.

Comment: @colapsnux I have updated my answer… try it and tell me. Thanks